# TeXLIVE fontmap entry duplicate warnings

Tags: fonts, texlive

I upgrade my OS a while ago (Fedora 37 -> 38) and since then I have been getting dozens of errors like this:

`` pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fontmap entry for `rtxptmri' already exists, duplicates ignored ``

I have tried reinstalling the txfonts and pxfonts packages as well as newtx and newpx, as well as a few packages that they depend on, but it only reduced the number of these warnings. I then tried reinstalling ALL TeXLIVE packages, and that changed the warnings to this:

`` pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): ambiguous entry for `txbttsl': font file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present ``

Again, there are dozens of these warnings every time I run pdflatex (to the extent that I miss "real" warnings such as needing to run latex again).

Any suggestions as to how to make the warnings go away?

Comment: try `updmap --sys --syncwithtrees`

Comment: This should also be reported to Fedora as it suggests one or more `texlive` packages is not being correctly installed. But you should check first you don't have font files in your home directory which are causing the problem. Do you have fonts and/or map files installed into `~/texmf/` or `~/.texlive2023` (assuming Fedora are giving you TL 2023 rather than 2022)?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I tried ``updmap --sys --syncwithtrees`` just now; it still occurs.

@cfr: I have thought about reporting this to Fedora, but I haven't been able to narrow down exactly what to report. Another Fedora 38 installation I have works fine, but that one started from Fedora 36 as a fresh install. The ones that don't work were upgraded from previous releases, and that's the only thing I can think of that ties them together.

Comment: I took one of my machines that was exhibiting this bug and uninstalled everything texlive-related (including things that depend on it such as octave and evince), blew away /usr/share/texlive, reinstalled all the packages, and the problem goes away. This is admittedly a bit like using a sledgehammer to kill ants, but it worked. This confirms that it was likely a file that was not deleted between Fedora 36 and 38, say (or perhaps 34 -> 36). I may report the problem to Fedora, but I'm guessing that my description won't be enough to make it easily fixable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This appears to be a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2020188) in the Fedora 34 to 35 upgrade path.

A comment on the issue tracker suggests the following fix, which indeed resolved the issue for me:

```
dnf remove texlive-updmap-map
rm /etc/texlive/web2c/updmap.cfg*
dnf reinstall texlive-texlive-scripts
```

Comment: The package it states to remove no longer exists, but if I follow the other two steps (i.e., remove the updmap.cfg file) and reinstall texlive-texlive-scripts, it resolves it. Thank you very much!